# Unable to ssh FROM Ubuntu on Windows 10 linux subsystem

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I attempt to ssh from Ubuntu running on my Surface Go tablet running the linux subsystem to Linux on my desktop PC, I get the error "Resource temporarily unavailable". I am able to ssh from my Laptop to the same desktop PC. I've disabled the firewall on the desktop PC and Surface Go running Linux, and still the same error. I know it's not a DNS issue, as I try to ssh to the IP address of my desktop PC.

Any ideas what would be preventing me from SSH'ing FROM this Surface Go to another host?

Comment: What do you see if you use a tool like nmap on the linux machine to scan the windows machine running the linux subsystem?   the command would be nmap <ip address of windows machine>.   Are you using the standard TCP port 22 for SSH?

Comment: Let me try an nmap tonight and I'll get back to you.  And yes, I am using the standard port 22.   -Thanks